# Jenkins build failure with debian-package-builder plugin: can't cd to directory

Tags: ubuntu, build, jenkins

I am trying to use the Jenkins plugin debian-package-builder to build a debian/ubuntu package.  The packaging itself isn't the problem, and manual builds using svn-buildpackage succeed.

The build process proceeds until it reaches the point of updating the changelog.  The output is as follows:

```
[debian-package-builder] running command <export DEBEMAIL= && export DEBFULLNAME=Jenkins && cd 'workspace/<...>/debian' && dch --check-dirname-level 0 -b --distributor debian --newVersion 1.r10649 'Build #19. Started by upstream project "my project" build number 19.'>
[ubuntu-12.04] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1444309539601954879.sh
+ export DEBEMAIL=
+ export DEBFULLNAME=Jenkins
+ cd workspace/<...>/debian
/tmp/hudson1444309539601954879.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to workspace/<...>/debian
```

The path the plugin computed is correct as a path relative to $JENKINS_HOME.  I can't seem to find any information as to what the current working directory is when jenkins runs the command.  Any pointers on how to correct this situation?

The build master is Ubuntu 13.10 with Jenkins 1.509.2.  The build slave is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.